# How to output to csv file using mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is a sample table of my original table USER_DETAILS, i want to export the user_id and user_phone fields to a csv file for further implementation in my project.

```
user_id    user_phone

1          9977660050
2          9977660051
3          9977660042
4          9977660080
```

**P.S.:** Please answer me the query for this, instead of giving abrupt answers and suggestions. i guess the table is quite clear to understand.

Comment: the person who downvoted my question is humbly requested to specify the correct reason for doing so. It is very rude to downvote without a reason.

Comment: Freak often people don't want to waste their time telling the OP that they could simply have done a simple google search for the answer [How to output csv with mysql](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+output+csv+with+php#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=how+to+output+csv+with+mysql&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b26d2f4496b7882f). Even SO prompts you to look at the other similar questions when you typed in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't really need this to be in PHP, just run:

```
SELECT user_id, user_phone INTO OUTFILE '/your/filepath'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM user_details;
```

Obviously, replace '/your/filepath' with the path to the file you want to save to.

Comment: Didn't know you could do this. +1

Comment: Wow, that is cool, I didn't know mysql could do that either. :)

Comment: hey @jacob and @masterz - i dont know why did someone downvote my question even if you people find it so interesting and cool. can you please help me get my reputation back?

Comment: @Coding-Freak Just give a good answer or something, you only lost 2 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to do this in PHP or just output it to a CSV file. Here's how to do the latter:

```
SELECT user_id, user_phone
FROM user_details
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/user_details.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: sorry, your answer is correct but i got the same answer from @zerocates 1 minute before you did. so i had to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 'User','User Phone'

UNION

SELECT user_id,user_phone INTO OUTFILE 'users.csv'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

FROM USER_DETAILS;